# Trouble converting php array to json format slightly wrong

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm having trouble getting the correct json format from the following php array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => name1
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [5] => 2013-15-6,9
                            [6] => 2013-15-7,9
                            [7] => 2013-15-8,9
                            [8] => 2013-15-9,9
                            [9] => 2013-15-10,9
                            [10] => 2013-15-11,9
                            [11] => 2013-15-12,9
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Encoding it to json outputs

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "data": [
            {
                "5": "2013-15-6,9",
                "6": "2013-15-7,9",
                "7": "2013-15-8,9",
                "8": "2013-15-9,9",
                "9": "2013-15-10,9",
                "10": "2013-15-11,9",
                "11": "2013-15-12,9"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

What I need the json output to look like is below, basically removing the curly brackets inside the data array and remove the index numbers thought I don't think that's possible.

```
[
    {
        "name": "name1",
        "data": [
            "2013-15-11,9",
            "2013-15-12,9"
        ]
    }
]
```

I've tried different combinations of array() around variables which got me close enough by adding the bracket inside the data array but I can't get rid of the curly brackets. Would really appreciate some help, have been working on this for a few hours. Thanks

Comment: Why are you working with pure JSON, I wonder? JSON is a mesh of key=>value pairs, I don't think you can get it to store a list of unindexed values. Can't you parse it before actually using the values?

Comment: Simply reset the keys in of the array under the `data` key, by either using `array_values` or `sort`.

Answer (score 1):

I took the json output that you are **expecting** to get and did `json_decode` on it, that's the result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
           [name] => name1
           [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 2013-15-11,9
                    [1] => 2013-15-12,9
                )

        )

)
```

So that's how your PHP structure should look like before sending it to `json_encode`.

P.S. I checked it with `json_encode` (reversed the process) and it returns exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is that even if you have not placed indexes directly, PHP will store them from `0`. I.e. the corresponding JSON may have no keys only if your array have consecutive indexes, starting from `0`. Otherwise, indexes **must** be placed - that is because resulting JSON must hold both keys and values.

See sample:

```
$rgData = ['a','b','c'];
var_dump(json_encode($rgData));//string(13) "["a","b","c"]"
unset($rgData[0]);//now we're going from 1 numeric key
var_dump(json_encode($rgData));//string(17) "{"1":"b","2":"c"}"
```

note, that in second case you have indexes, starting from `1` - and  JSON **must** hold that. The only way to do this - is to pass indexes.

You can transform array to consecutive keys via:

```
$rgData = [5=>'a',6=>'b',7=>'c'];
$rgData = array_values($rgData);
var_dump($rgData);//array(3) { [0]=> string(1) "a" [1]=> string(1) "b" [2]=> string(1) "c" }
```

Comment: Was pulling my hair out on that one.. It almost seems counter intuitive to unset something and not remove it like a array_splice does, but I guess the "key" is that all arrays associative under the hood.

Answer (score 0):

By overwriting `[0]['data']` with a new indexed array of the values in `[0]['data'][0]', you can restructure your data in one line.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/716d5bf4c9ba419ea71e5aa3966cad1c7c03573e))

```
$array=[
            ['name'=>'name1',
             'data'=>[
                 [
                     5=>'2013-15-6,9',
                     6=>'2013-15-7,9',
                     7=>'2013-15-8,9',
                     8=>'2013-15-9,9',
                     9=>'2013-15-10,9',
                     10=>'2013-15-11,9',
                     11=>'2013-15-12,9'
                 ]
              ]
            ]
        ];
$array[0]['data']=array_values($array[0]['data'][0]);
echo json_encode($array);
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "name":"name1",
        "data":[
            "2013-15-6,9",
            "2013-15-7,9",
            "2013-15-8,9",
            "2013-15-9,9",
            "2013-15-10,9",
            "2013-15-11,9",
            "2013-15-12,9"
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: @Anagio Yes, this is an old question, but I don't think it can be sensibly  used to close new duplicate questions without a green tick on a clean/accurate/clear solution.  Let's contribute to a better SO.